# Удаление объекта из одного потока во время исполнения метода в другом (способ защиты)

Tags: многопоточность, c++11, c++

Есть поток который постоянно пробегается по достаточно большому вектору и у каждого объекта вызывает определенный вектор. Есть другой поток(по сути *GC*) который при определенных условиях извлекает некоторые объекты из вектора и удаляет их.

Есть два вопроса:

1. Приведет ли удаление объекта, во время исполнение его методов(с обращением к внутренним полям объекта) к непредсказуемому/нестабильному поведению программы?
2. Если да, то какой из способов защиты будет менее затратный по времени: Mutex или Умный указатель? (какие еще могут быть варианты для c++11?)

Спасибо.

Comment: если у Вас возникла задача такого типа, значит Вам нужно перейти на языки Java, C# или C++/cli. Последний, хоть и со странностями, но отвечает Вашим требованиям.

Наименее затратным будет создание отдельного потока, которому другие потоки будут сбрасывать объекты на удаление. Но все равно, придется делать свой умный указатель с мютексом внутри.

Comment: Понятие удаления объекта среди людей, работающих с C++, хорошо известно и определено: это вызов деструктора.

Comment: Это не должно быть ответом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно более эффективным будет другой подход (без GC в другом потоке).

Перед каждой очередной пробежкой по большому вектору, Вы вычисляете условие, при котором по нему шел бы поток GC и запускаете функцию GC для этого вектора (в том же потоке).

Разумеется, она должна уметь эффективно уплотнять вектор (IMHO тривиальный v.erase() каждый раз будет сдвигать хвост влево).

Затем продолжаете свои игры (нормальный ход алгоритма).

Конечно, у этого подхода есть определенные минусы (прежде всего код "захламляется"), но в плюс - большая предсказуемость тестирования (IMHO) и м.б. скорость обработки.

Answer (score 7):

1. Удаление объекта, с которым работает другой поток — классический случай undefined behaviour. Не делайте так.
2. В C++ настоящий GC реализовать довольно сложно, я бы пошёл по рекомендуемому пути и воспользовался `shared_ptr`. Однако, если вам нужно работать с объектом (не с указателем на него!) из нескольких потоков, вам понадобится mutex.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Ситуация изменилась так, что теперь несколько потоков используют(постоянно читают и изменяют поля) эти объекты. Пока все объекты защитил mutex'ами.
Но тогда объект блокируется для всех остальных потоков.
Может лучше организовать блокировку на уровне данных? Но тогда придется придумать какой-нибудь флаг(mutex?) для GC.

Или использовать для объекта shared_ptr, а для внутренних getter'ов/setter'ов mutex'ы?

Comment: @deterok, вообще-то для ответа на подобные вопросы IMHO нужно поподробнее описать задачу, основные алгоритмы и структуры данных. 

--

В векторе(ах?) у Вас сами инстансы или указатели? 

Размер вектора? 

Источник входных данных (человек с мышью, видеокамера или программа моделирования?), их интенсивность?

И т.п.

Только осознав ответы на подобные запросы можно говорить о том, какой подход к обработке *лучше*. 

--

Между прочим, не забывайте, что механизмы синхронизации (мьютексы) и запуск потоков довольно медленны.

Comment: @deterok: Если у вас много потоков постоянно читают и изменяют данные, поиграть с гранулярностью блокировок — хорошая идея. Не забудьте, что деструктор уничтожает _все_ данные, так что вам понадобится «максимальная» блокировка, если вы выбрали блокировку по полям.

---
Если разные потоки обновляют разные поля, можно попробовать так: поток защищает объект от удаления, клонирует объект, модифицирует нужные поля (тем временем с объектом могут работать другие потоки), а затем блокирует исходный объект и «вливает» в него изменения. Это может работать, если у вас поля независимы.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Воспользовался методом @avp.